# Does /usr/bin/top tool aggregate CPU and GPU usage in a single value?

Tags: cpu, top, gpu

I'm recently trying some crypto-coin mining and both on my desktop equipped with a decent GPU as well as on an AWS virtual machine with GPU support, CPU time is always reported at 99% by /usr/bin/top utility while mining.

Now the fact is that as far as i know while GPU mining CPU should not be involved in the process that much (GPU should do the whole job), so my question is: does anyone know if the aforementioned tool or Linux itself aggregates somehow CPU and GPU activity under a single value?

Note that I'm already aware about the existence of specific tools to monitor GPU activity (e.g. like nvidia-smi for nvidia cards, which in this specific case I use to confirm GPU activity) but I'm not interested in measuring that: I'm more interested in confirming if CPU might be effectively involved in the process or not.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Top does not monitor GPU activity, it only outputs information regarding the CPUs listed in /proc/cpuinfo.  I would check there to verify for sure:

```
less /proc/cpuinfo
```

Top lists by core by default as well, which further leads me to believe you have high cpu usage.

Also, just because you have GPU support, doesn't mean that its being utilized automatically. You have to specifically send instructions to the gpu, and not all programs can.  You have to implement the driver somehow, most likely through an API like CUDA. I believe CUDA and similar APIs come with GPU monitoring tools already, so I would inquire as to what API(s) are provided by AWS.